# Eigendecomposition in tensorflow from python API

Tags: eigenvalue, tensorflow

What would be the best way to achieve an iterative eigendecomposition using TensorFlow? (something like matlabs eigs).

I know that Eigen has the ability to perform an eigendecomposition, but it is unclear to me how to access this from the tensorflow python API. If tensorflow is just acting as an API to Eigen, then would there be any advantage over simply using scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs?

Answer (score 2):

tf.self_adjoint_eig and tf.batch_self_adjoint_eig are all I see in the API, 
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow does not currently expose a generic eigendecomposition operator. There are two main options:

- [Add a new C++ operator](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) that invokes Eigen's eigendecomposition functions. Since this may be generally useful, you might consider contributing it to the project in a [pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pulls).
- Use the [`tf.py_func()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func) op to run a Python function in your graph, and have this function call [`scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html).

The main benefit of the C++ operator is that it would avoid serialization overhead (copying the arrays to and from Python), and it would be portable to other platforms (e.g. Android, iOS) that do not always have a Python interpreter available.